# Is {$x|x=x\times x$} a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is {$x|x=x\times x$} a set?

We are working in ZFC.

I think it is not a set, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: What does $\times$ represent? Multiplication of real numbers? Cross product of vectors? Cartesian product of sets?

Comment: It is the cartesian product of sets.

Comment: What sets other than $x = \emptyset$ satisfy $x = x \times x$?

Comment: @Gauloises are you sure they're equal? There's clearly a bijection between them but I'm not sure if they are equal as sets.

Comment: I think that will depend on your definition of product. For instance it is not true that $A\times (B\times C)$ and $(A\times B)\times C$ are equal as sets if you use the usual Kuratowski definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some interpretation for "$z=(x,y)$", namely an ordered pair. This can be Kuratowski's definition, or it can be any other pairing function. This defines the notion of $A\times B$.

Now it depends on the way you encode ordered pairs, it might be the case that $\{\varnothing\}\times\{\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$, but it might be that it is not.

For example, in the case of the Kuratowski definition we have that $X\times X=X$ if and only if $X=\varnothing$. Because if $X$ is non-empty, and $X\times X=X$, then pick some $x_0\in X$, we have that $x_0=(x_1,y_1)$, and that $x_1=(x_2,y_2)$ and so on and so forth (because every element of $X$ is an ordered pair of elements of $X$). This defines a sequence of sets, $$\ldots\in x_n\in\{x_n\}\in x_{n-1}\in\{x_{n-1}\}\in\ldots\in\{x_1\}\in x_0$$
And this is a contradiction for regularity.

But again, this depends on the meaning of $A\times B$. It should also be noted, that as **sets** $2^\omega$ and $2^\omega\times2^\omega$ are not the same. They are isomorphic as groups, or linear orders, or whatever. But they are not the same set!

Comment: So {$x|x\times x=x$}={$\emptyset$} and it is a set. Thank you.

Comment: If your definition of Cartesian product based on the Kuratowski ordered pair, then yes.

Comment: But of course "$\times$" is not part of the ZFC formalism, so perhaps you get other answers if you use other versions of it.  Thus, your question should include a definitoin of "$\times$".